# Nuxt static site on GAE 404 on page refresh

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, nuxt.js

I know there are already several posts on this topic, but I did not get this thing to work with the recommended settings. When I generate and start my Nuxt static site locally with the following commands, everything works fine. Even when I refresh the page, the same route is displayed.

```
nuxt generate && nuxt start
```

When I deploy my `dist` folder to Google App Engine, the site seems to work like a charm. However, as soon if I hit the refresh button, a 404 is displayed. My `app.yaml` looks as follows:

```
---
runtime: python37
instance_class: F1

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html
  secure: always
- url: /(.*)
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*)
  secure: always
```

Applicable `nuxt.config.js` settings:

```
ssr: true
target: 'static'
```

Answer (score 1):

Managed to fix this in the `app.yaml`, but not 100% sure why this happened. It probably has to do with the "catch-all" handler on the end. Here is my working example:

```
---
runtime: python37
instance_class: F1

handlers:
  - url: /(.*\..+)$
    static_files: \1
    upload: (.*\..+)$
  - url: /.*
    static_files: index.html
    upload: index.html
```